# How to prevent xml.ElementTree fromstring from dropping commentnode

Tags: python, xml, elementtree

I have tho following code fragment:

```
    from xml.etree.ElementTree import fromstring,tostring
    mathml = fromstring(input)
    for elem in mathml.getiterator():
        elem.tag = 'm:' + elem.tag
    return tostring(mathml)
```

When i input the following `input`:

```
<math>
  <a> 1 2 3 </a>  <b />
<foo>Uitleg</foo>
<!-- <bar> -->
</math>
```

It results in:

```
<m:math>
  <m:a> 1 2 3 </m:a>  <m:b />
<m:foo>Uitleg</m:foo>

</m:math>
```

How come? And how can I preserve the comment?

**edit**: I don't care for the exact xml library used, however, I should be able to do the pasted change to the tags. Unfortunately, lxml does not seem to allow this (and I cannot use proper namespace operations)

Comment: I don't think that is possible with the current implementation of `xml.etree`. Comment nodes are stripped to begin with by the parser.

Comment: But then I should be able to solve it by using a different parser? (assuming there is one which does not drop comments). Because ElementTree does have CommentNode's, which you can create, so I would expect some support somewhere.

Comment: It's true. `xml.etree` *can* create a Comment node and serialize it to XML, but the reverse is not supported by its default parser, unfortunately.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You cannot with `xml.etree`, because its parser ignores comments (which is acceptable behaviour for an xml parser by the way). But you can if you use the (compatible) [lxml](http://lxml.de/) library, which allows you to configure [parser options](http://lxml.de/parsing.html#parsers).

```
from lxml import etree

parser = etree.XMLParser(remove_comments=False)
tree = etree.parse('input.xml', parser=parser)
# or alternatively set the parser as default:
# etree.set_default_parser(parser)
```

This would by far be the easiest option. If you really have to use xml.etree, you could try hooking up your own parser, although even then, comments are not officially supported: have a look at [this example](http://effbot.org/zone/element-pi.htm) (from the author of xml.etree) (still seems to work in python 2.7 by the way)

Comment: That seems to work, however, lxml does not allow my hacky namespace-addition (and I do not want to do it properly; my xml files get postprocessed by unknown scripts, and I don't know the consequences of adding proper namespaces, as they're not in use currently).

Comment: You can also do this with xml.dom.minidom ; both the toxml() and toprettyxml() methods preserve comments. (I can't easily use lxml because I'm writing an add-on that should preferably be cross-platform, which seems easiest to do using pure Python.)