# Find/replace an URL in document using Python regex

Tags: python, xml, regex

Experts of Python regular expressions! I'm trying to change a line in a xml document.
The original line is:

```
<Tag name="low"     Value="%hello%\dir"/>
```

The result I want to see is:

```
<Tag name="low"     Value="C:\art"/>
```

My failed straight-forward attempt is:

```
lines = re.sub("%hello%\dir"", "C:\art"/>
```

This doesn't work. Doesn't change anything in the doc. Something with %?

For testing purposes I tried:

```
lines = re.sub("dir", "C:\art", a)
```

And I get:

```
<Tag name="low"     Value="%hello%\C:BELrt"/>
```

The problem is that \a = [BEL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bell_character).

I've tried a bunch of other things, but to no avail. How do I go about this problem?

Comment: Are you sure you need regex?  Looks like you could get by with simple [replace()](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#str.replace) method calls?

Answer (score 0):

In Python, use the `r` prefix to a literal string to keep from having to escape your slashes. Then escape your slash to avoid `\d` matching a digit.

```
lines = re.sub(r"%hello%\\dir", r"C:\\art")
```

Comment: `r'\d'` means match a digit in a regex

Comment: the `r'\a'` in the `repl` part also should be escaped. also `/>` -> `)`

Answer (score 0):

You're issue is that you've got some characters which have specific meaning in regex's.

`\d` means any digit. `%hello%\dir` is then `%hello%[0-9]ir`

You need to escape those slashes/use a raw string to get around this:

```
a = '''<Tag name="low" Value="%hello%\dir"/>'''
lines = re.sub(r"%hello%\\dir", r"C:\\art", a)
print(lines) #<Tag name="low"     Value="C:\\art"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

It is a good question. It shows three issues with a text representation at once:

- `'\a'` Python string literal is a single BELL character.

  To input backslash followed by letter 'a' in Python source code you need either use raw-literals: `r'\a'` or escape the slash `'\\a'`.
- `r'\d'` (two characters) has special meaning when interpreted as a regular expression (`r'\d'` means match a digit in a regex).

  In addition to rules for Python string literals you also need to escape possible regex metacharacters. You could use `re.escape(your_string)` in general case or just `r'\\d'` or `'\\\\d'`. `'\a'` in the `repl` part should also be escaped (twice in your case: `r'\\a'` or `'\\\\a'`):

  ```py
  >>> old, new = r'%hello%\dir', r'C:\art'
  >>> print re.sub(re.escape(old), new.encode('string-escape'), xml)
  <Tag name="low"     Value="C:\art"/>
  ```

  btw, you don't need regular expressions at all in this case:

  ```py
  >>> print xml.replace(old, new)
  <Tag name="low"     Value="C:\art"/>
  ```
- at last [XML attribute value can't contain certain characters](http://www.w3.org/TR/2000/REC-xml-20001006#syntax) that are also should be escaped e.g., `'&'`, `'"'`, `"<"`, etc.

In general you should not use regex to manipulate XML. Python's stdlib has XML parsers.

```py
>>> import xml.etree.cElementTree as etree
>>> xml = r'<Tag name="low"     Value="%hello%\dir"/>'
>>> tag = etree.fromstring(xml)
>>> tag.set('Value', r"C:\art & design")
>>> etree.dump(tag)
<Tag Value="C:\art &amp; design" name="low" />
```

Comment: Thanks a lot!
By the way, after the `etree.fromstring(xml)` all comments are left out.
How do you parse the XML document with comments?

Comment: @RenataPre: [How to prevent xml.ElementTree fromstring from dropping commentnode](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5411766/4279)