# How to inject escape sequences in python

Tags: python

I need to put escape sequences in a string for certain characters (using double quote as an example here). For example, if I have a string `abra"cada"bra`, I need to generate this: `abra\"cada\"bra`. But if the string is already has escape characters for my interested literals (i.e double quote in this example) `abra\"cada\"bra`, I need to leave it alone.
What is the easiest way to do it in python?

(The idea is to write it to a text file which is read by another utility.)

Comment: what is the expected output if the escape character is itself escaped: `abra\\"cada\\"bra`?

Comment: @J. F. Sebastian - good question! The regex lookback gets more complicated.

Answer (score 2):

It's probably easiest to just decode the string first, so that nothing is escaped, then re-escape the resulting string.

Answer (score 1):

You can get it with the appropriate negative look behind assertion in regular expressions:

```
import re

PAT = re.compile(r'(?<!\\)"')
txt1 = '"abra"cada"bra'
txt2 = '\\"abra\\"cada\\"bra'
print PAT.sub(r'\\"', txt1)
print PAT.sub(r'\\"', txt2)
```

This would make sure, it even works correctly, if the quote is the first character of the sting, as in the example above.

Comment: Oh gosh, some remanscence of previous trials. I corrected it now. Thanks!

Comment: see also [my comments to @tdelaney's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15298267/how-to-inject-escape-sequences-in-python/15298584#comment21591970_15298584)

Comment: Sure, and I completly agree that it may be a better strategy to go (I've already upvoted your answer :-)). Probably I'd do the unescaping and escaping with regular expressions, so that one can  do it for more than one special character (e.g. ' and ") at the same time...

Comment: To allow specifying escape sequence dynamically: `e, c = '\\"'; print re.sub(r"(?<!{}){}".format(*map(re.escape,[e,c])), (e+c).encode('string-escape'), r'a"b\"c')`. [Related issue.](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12863734/4279)

Answer (score 1):

something like this

```
def esc_string(mystring, delim, esc_char='\\'):
    return (esc_char+delim).join([s[:-1] if s.endswith(esc_char) else s for s in mystring.split(delim)])
```

then

```
print esc_string('abra"cada"bra', '"')
abra\"cada\"bra
print esc_string('abra\\"cada\\"bra', '"')
abra\"cada\"bra
print esc_string('"boundary test"', '"')
\"boundary test\"
print esc_string('\\"boundary test\\"', '"')
\"boundary test\"
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming `\` has no special meaning other than immediately before certain characters (e.g.,`'"'`) then [@chepner's suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15298354/4279) to unescape first could be implemented as:

```
def escape(text, char='"', escape="\\"):
    escaped_char = escape + char
    text = text.replace(escaped_char, char) # unescape
    return text.replace(char, escaped_char) # escape
```

#### [Input](http://ideone.com/jEGS2M)

```
"abra"cada"bra\"
\"abra\"cada\"bra"
"abra\"cada"bra\"
abra\"cada\\"bra\"
abra\"cada\\\"bra\"
```

#### Output

```
\"abra\"cada\"bra\"
\"abra\"cada\"bra\"
\"abra\"cada\"bra\"
abra\"cada\\"bra\"
abra\"cada\\\"bra\"
```

Answer (score 0):

Regular expressions will do it. This one says to match the " character if it is not preceded by a backslash. I used an 'r' at the front of the strings to tell python not to treat the '\' character specially and I had to put it in twice to tell the regular expression parser not to use it specially. Try help(re) for what the (?

```
import re
re.sub(r'(?<!\\)"', r'\"', 'abra"cada\\"bra')
# Returns 'abra\\"cada\\"bra'
```

Comment: how do you escape the replacement argument in general case (OP says that `'"'` is just an example). Consider what happens if `'1'` is used instead of `'"'`.

Comment: @J.F. Sebastian - The (?<!...) part is a negative lookback (don't match if \ precedes what I am looking for). The " is the thing I'm looking for. I can replace " with a set of characters using []:  `r'(?<!\\)["1x]'` would escape " 1 and x.

Comment: I meant the second argument of `re.sub()` where `\1` has special meaning. It is hard to implement `escape(text, char)` using a single `re.sub()`.

Comment: The tricky part is to handle 4 escape contexts: Python string literal, regex pattern, `re.sub`'s `repl` argument, and finally the rules from the question.