# How can I use python to remove xml node

Tags: python, xml

I want to remove elements from xml files. When I was using ElementTree, I can get all the elements from xml files, but I cannot get the xml statements and annotations.
So if I use:

```
# get xml nodes
tree = ElementTree.pares()
# do filter things ...
# write to files
tree.write(file_path)
```

I will miss all the statements and annotations. Is there a way to remove xml elements from *.xml files and keep the annotations, statements or any other things in the files?

For example, the source:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- I am annotation -->
<string name="name">content</string><string left="left">left things</string>
```

And my target:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- I am annotation -->
<string left="left">left things</string>
```

But when I use tree.write(file_path), it will miss the annotation and statement, become:

```
<string left="left">left things</string>
```

Comment: You want to remove the _nodes_ or just the _tags_? A node is a tag with its contents.

Comment: Sorry, I mean elements.  I have fixed the description.

Comment: Could you make a source XML and target XML example?

Comment: OK, I have added an example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Possible using [`lxml`](http://lxml.de/) which provide `remove_comments=False` option to preserve XML comments :

```
from lxml import etree

parser = etree.XMLParser(remove_comments=False)
tree = etree.parse("input.xml", parser=parser)
root = tree.getroot()

for c in root.findall(".//string[@name='name']"):
    root.remove(c)

tree.write("output.xml")
```

"input.xml" :

```
<root>
<!-- I am annotation -->
<string name="name">content</string><string left="left">left things</string>
</root>
```

"output.xml" :

```
<root>
<!-- I am annotation -->
<string left="left">left things</string>
</root>
```

Related question :

- [How to prevent xml.ElementTree fromstring from dropping commentnode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5409161/how-to-prevent-xml-elementtree-fromstring-from-dropping-commentnode)

Answer (score 0):

Use https://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
tree = ET.parse('data.xml')
root = tree.getroot()

for country in root.findall('//string[@name='left']'):
    root.remove(country)        

tree.write('output_data.xml')
```

Comment: I know this way, then I will miss the annotation. Is there any other way?